# How to run unit tests in nunit latest version(3.0.5813) in console

Tags: nunit, nunit-console, nunit-3.0

I have tried following command in command prompt.

```
C:\ProgramFiles()x86\nunit.org\nunit-console>"nunit3-console.exe" "E:\UnitTesting\TestsProject\obj\Release\Tests.dll"
```

I am getting the following error in console.
[image: nunit console error message]

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NUnit 3 will by default try and write the test results to the working directory.

Your working directory here is Program Files, which it appears the process does not have permission to write to. You can set a different directory for the output files using the `--work` option. ([Docs](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line))